# update user info in array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, middleware

i am having an issue, i want to update hobbies as a array (like- {"hobbies":["running","dancing"]} )

User is a model.

```js
    router.patch('/userInfo', async (req, res) => {
    const updates = Object.keys(req.body);
    const allowedUpdates = ['userId', 'userImages','intrestedIn', 'hobbies']`

    const isValidOperation = updates.every((update) => {
      return allowedUpdates.includes(update)
    });

    if (!isValidOperation) {
      return res.send({
        error: "Validation fail"
      })
    }

    try {

      const user = await User.findOne({ _id: req.body.userId }, req.body)
      console.log(user)
      if (!user) {
        return res.send({
          error: 'Invalid user Id'
        })
      }
      updates.forEach((update) => {
        user[update] = req.body[update]
      })
      await user.save()

      return res.send({ user })
    } catch (e) {
      res.send(e)
    }
})
```

and output is that, but i want array(like intrestedIn output)

```js
{
    "user": {
        "intrestedIn": [
            "Female"
        ],
        "hobbies": [
            "{\"hobbies\":[\"dancing\",\"running\"]} "
        ],
        "_id": "5ec71c43026b2f1d640b657f"
       }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add a sample `req.body` JSON

Comment: @Vishnu yes i can, then i have to make if and else condition but i want to query in one condition.

Comment: BTW can you elaborate in coding language

Comment: Please include the schema of `User`